# Lookup a specific rowvalue when the column depends on another cell (row/column combination)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have an excel sheet with a very large, scarcely populated matrix.
The first column describes an item, and the columns after that whether an item belongs to a certain group. Each item can only belong to one group.
However, instead of having one single column that indicates the group of each item, the whole thing has been spread out into multiple dummy columns (one per group) where an x indicates if the item belongs to that group or not.

What I have:

| Item |  | Group_1 | Group_2 | Group_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | x |  |  |
| 2 |  | x |  |  |
| 3 |  |  | x |  |
| 4 |  |  |  | x |
| 5 |  |  |  | x |

What I want:

| Item | Group | Group_1 | Group_2 | Group_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Group_1 | x |  |  |
| 2 | Group_1 | x |  |  |
| 3 | Group_2 |  | x |  |
| 4 | Group_3 |  |  | x |
| 5 | Group_3 |  |  | x |

Also, for this example, I've named the groups "group_1", "group_2", etc. but in the real data frame, their name could be anything.
What is the best way to solve this problem? From what I see xlookup/vlookup/hlookup depend on two predetermined cell ranges that are then compared. But here everything depends on the row/column combination as indicated by the "x".

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem for the `INDEX/MATCH` approach to lookups although this one looks horizontally rather than the usual vertically.

Use:

```
=INDEX( $C$1:$E$1, 1, MATCH("x",C2:E2,0) )
```

`MATCH()` looks across the row rather than down a column, so its result is the column parameter in `INDEX()` rather than the usual row parameter.

However, `XLOOKUP()` is fully able to do this as well:

```
=XLOOKUP( "x", C2:E2, $C$1:$E$1 )
```

and gives some built-in options of interest, one being what to do if the lookup value is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether Power Query is helpful.

First you can select and right-click the data > Get data from table/range.

Select the blank column to remove.

[image]

Select Group_1 > go to Add Column tab > General group > Duplicate Column.

[image]

Please repeat this action for Group_2 and Group_3.

Then press Ctrl tp select Group_1, Group_2 and Group_3, go to Transform tab > Any Column group > Unpivot Column

[image]

[image]

Delete the Value column, and click Close & Load to, load the table to your sheet.

[image]